# Best Practices for Scalable File Storage

Tags: java, file-storage

Say we are writing applications with Play Framework, or Spring for instance, and we want to use a standard way to manage and store binary file uploads using an API (object storage), as opposed to managing a file system yourself.  In a similar way to using Amazon cloud storage, but without locking into an external provider.

Imagine we would also like to be able start by running this service on the same server as the application you are developing, until growth requires it you to move the file storage to it's own server (or cluster) and your application itself in it's own cluster. If we start off with a cluster-ready service then surely we can scale up quickly.

Do we continue to manage the file system ourselves while running at a small scale, or do we adopt something else?

Is this where we need to look at running a local Hadoop HDFS instance for example, this way we wouldn't need to rewrite our file upload and handling in our application, and could scale-out the file management system into a cluster when the need arises. It would be great if this functionality was provided as a service with a common API, such as running H2DB in-memory for integration testing.

Or are Hadoop HDFS, OpenStack Swift or Ceph overkill when we're still making our simple prototype application?

I'm sure that I'm missing something - but struggling to find the solution. Managing a file system by hand feels dirty and wouldn't allow me to push applications to any PaaS provider without rewriting. Again, I think there should also be a local solution rather than always integrating with Amazon and the likes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hadoop HDFS is used to store very large files (multiple GB of text in one file) and prozess it in parallel.

Comment: Have you looked at GridFS which is included with MongoDB? (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: I use Cassandra for this in my project and from what I've researched/read, so does Netflix. You treat your byte arrays (blobs) just like you would with any other database with the exception that the distribution is done for you for free and is linearly scalable. It also provides replication strategies so you can be sure your data is sufficiently safe in case of node failure.

Comment: @kha: the Cassandra FAQ kind of discourages this: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#large_file_and_blob_storage

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True but for smaller files that don't require streaming (and are small enough to be loaded into memory), it's valid. If the files are too big to be comfortably loaded into memory (which is not my usecase), you can use https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax which is from Netflix and provides a streaming interface for loading the files from Cassandra which I imagine no longer attempts to load the entire row into memory (I haven't used it though so don't know for sure but I imagine Netflix are loading huge files so it somehow works).

Comment: Correction: Apparently astyanax breaks the file into chunks (https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Chunked-Object-Store) and then stiches the chunks back together when loading the file.

Comment: Can Cassandra run almost as lightweight as an in-memory database - just thinking about the full spectrum of development (prototyping, test automation, single node deployment and finally large environment/clusters)